# python joblib.Parallel vs Parallel-Python: parallelise over multiple cores of a single CPU?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, parallel-processing, pp-python-parallel

I want to parallelize the execution of a for loop written in python-2.7 on the quadcore processor of my computer's CPU.

Shall I implement this with joblib.Parallel or with Parallel-Python?

I've seen joblib.Parallel being used more, but the first line of [this](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html#using-the-threading-backend) part of its documentation worried me: it sets forked processes to work on "separate CPUs". Does that mean it can't do it on separate cores of the same CPU?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

joblib versus Parallel-Python is primarily opinion-based which is defined as Off-Topic for Stackoverflow. But as for the other part of your question:

By CPU, I think they are referring to core.

```
import joblib
print joblib.cpu_count()
```

Gives `8` on my computer, which is exactly the number of cores I have, and I only have one CPU.

They are also based on top of `multiprocessing` which states:

> ... the multiprocessing module allows the programmer to fully leverage multiple processors on a given machine.

Comment: Though you could add pros and cons of both joblib and Parallel-Python. It'll help future viewers like me. Thanks!